# Javascript not working i put this in dom.ready in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this code in my JS file. If i remove the the if else loops then i can get the hello as alert otherwise not.

Neither i am getting any error in firebug console

Basically in those loops i am just checking if the url contains few keywords so that ican chnage the css to selected

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var userPage = /child\/(.+)/.exec(location.href)[1];        
    if( userPage.indexOf('show') != -1 )
        {$('.profile').addClass('selected');}           
    if( userPage.indexOf('workbook') != -1 )
    {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.workbook').addClass('selected');
    }
    if( userPage.indexOf('gallery') != -1 )
    {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.gallery').addClass('selected');
    }
    if( userPage.indexOf('mylist') != -1 )
    {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.mylist').addClass('selected');
    }

    if( userPage.indexOf('Photos') != -1 )
    {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.photos').addClass('selected');
    }

    if( userPage.indexOf('profile/list') != -1 )
    {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.list').addClass('selected');
    }                   
    alert("hillo");
```

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: I get an error on `var userPage = /child\/(.+)/.exec(location.href)[1];` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Your regex is not matching, you have not handled that case.

Comment: regex error, you can check it first

Comment: What is the value of `location.href` (or, more simply, what is the URL of the page)? It obviously doesn't match the regex `/child\/(.+)/`.

Comment: _"if else loops"_ Terminology correction: a "loop" is a `for` or `while` statement that executes the same statement or block of code repeatedly. (When it gets to the end of the block it "loops" back around to the beginning...)

Comment: i am not seeing any error on firefox console , why is that. i agree that regex is not matching , but does that suppose tobe shown on console. Also how handle that case if regex don't match and i don't get any error. Also is there any better way to accomplish above code. it looks too messy

Comment: If you are not seeing any errors on the console, where did you see the error that you previously reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've set it up the alert is not inside any if statement, so it should alert no matter what. If there is no alert you're script has errors, and I spot at least two :

You're assuming the url contains the string `child/`, if it does not your script will halt and not work, next you're assuming the output of that `exec()` is an array with at least two values, selecting the second value of that array, and if for some reason your url does not contain `child/` there will be no second value in that array, and the script halts, but then again it already halted in the `exec()`.

The second error is that the `document.ready` function is'nt closed, thats probably just a typo.

On the other hand you should figure out a way to do this more dynamically. You're using the same class as the url string you are checking for, so for most of the cases you could just use it directly in the selector, cutting your function down to just a few lines, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://somesite.com/child/gallery'; //just a test url

    var userPage = url.indexOf('child/') != -1 ? /child\/(.+)/.exec(url)[1] : null;

    if (userPage) {
        console.log('has child in url');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('.'+userPage).addClass('selected');

    }else{
        console.log('not ok');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns null in the first line of your code.

var userPage = /child/(.+)/.exec(location.href)[1];

and you must get this error ": Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null"

its better to check first whether the url has child or not then proceed.